# How do I replace special characters in an XML file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to replace all the `<`, `>`, and `"` in a file. I am using the following but it is failing.

```
powershell.exe -Command (Get-Content C:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml) |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace '\<', '&#60;' `
           -replace '>', '&#62;' `
           -replace '\"', '&#62;'
} | Set-Content c:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. A couple of comments on your question. Your code is not well formatted which makes it difficult to read. You tend to get more help when your questions are easier for others to read. Simply saying 'it is failing' is not useful. Explaining the specific error is. In cases where you are looking to transform something (like text) many people find it helpful when you provide example input and example expected output.

Comment: "it is failing" is not a valid problem description. What result do you expect? What result do you actually get? Are there errors? What do they say?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to replace angular brackets and double quotes in an XML file in the first place? Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for? What do you want to do with the modified file?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quoting issue while trying to pass a value into `-Command`.

If this is being called from within a PowerShell console, the following will work.

```
Powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Content C:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml) -replace '\<','&#60;' -replace '\>','&#62;' -replace '\`"', '&#62;' | Set-Content c:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml"
```

If this is being called from CMD, the following will work:

```
Powershell.exe -Command "(Get-Content C:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml) -replace '\<','&#60;' -replace '\>','&#62;' -replace '\""', '&#62;' | Set-Content c:\Users\dearo05\Documents\founders\annual_dividend_cov.xml"
```

The value passed into `-Command` should be surrounded by double quotes. The easiest way to do this is to turn all double quotes inside of the value to single quotes where possible and then escape the double quotes within the value. If called from a PowerShell session, you need to backtick escape the inner double quotes (`"). If called from within CMD.exe, you need to double quote escape the quotes ("").

Comment: The system I am reading this into does not like the special characters so I thought replacing them and it would convert them for me. Thanks that did the trick